# Dns records conflict between zones

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Let's say we have intranet.domain.local defined private ip set up in windows dns server.
Now, we connect vpn to our mother company and want their intranet.mother.com resolve to another private ip.
I tried setting up new zone "intranet.mother.com" with A record - worked ok, but intranet started being resolved to this, so https://intranet stopped working correctly. If I could set domain.local higher priority in case of conflict, that would resolve the issue.

Next, I tried setting up a new A record in domain.local doesn't work- intranet.mother.com does not resolve, only intranet.mother.com.domain.local does.

Of course I can't setup mother.com zone, becuase I want public addresses like [www.mother.com](http://www.mother.com) to resolve externally.

Any solution besides setting up hosts file for every workstation?

Answer (score 0):

That's what conditional forwarders in Window's DNS server are there for.
The reason why `intranet.mother.com.domain.local` resolves, my guess is the appended connection suffix, which is the local `domain.local`.
`intranet` should internally resolve to intranet.domain.local
`intranet.mother.com` should stay and not append the local suffix.
You can verify that with Wireshark and nslookup.
You can append a `.` (dot) to the end of a domain (marks the root zone) to prevent suffix appending.
e.g. `intranet.mother.com.`

Comment: Conditional forwarder not usable (mother's internal DNS server not accessible). Solution with dot at the end of host name- I tried adding this into host name record- editing FQDN not possible- ends up with error: The host record intranet.mother.com..domain.local cannot be created. The name is invalid. I also tried adding the dot to the name of forward zone- result is it does not resolve. Somewhere else I should use this dot hack?

Comment: You should have used it with nslookup not within the dns server. Also the conditional forwarder in your dns server not in the mother domain.

Comment: So you meant create intranet.mother.com. as new forward lookup zone? I can't use DNS forwarding because VPN will not allow UDP 53.

Comment: If DNS is not allowed in the VPN then you can't use conditional forwarders. But yes, you can create a new zone for `intranet.mother.com`.

Comment: If I do that, intranet starts to resolve to IP of intranet.mother.com instead of intranet.domain.local. I don't know why it prioritize local domain. Guess I will need to use hostname file after all. :(

Comment: Which connection specific DNS suffixes are set in your network interface? Do you supply multiple via DHCP? You can use `Get-DnsClient | fl`.

Comment: Single DHCP and Get-DnsClient | fl reports correctly ConnectionSpecificSuffix domain.local.

Comment: I have just tried adding A record intranet2 to domain.local zone and create intranet2.mother.com. Strangely, running nslookup on the DNS server itself translates intrantet2 correctly to intranet2.domain.local, but on a workstation, the nslookup on the the same server reports IP of intranet2.mother.com.

Comment: Lol, guess what, the host file acts in the same manner. Adding intranet.mother.com causes intranet translate to intranet.mother.com, ignoring FQDN and domain suffix of domain.local completely. Had to manually add intranet to the hosts file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason and a solution.
Looking into:
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters
"SearchList" defines which domains to search with priority from left to right.
All I had to do was replacing "mother.com,domain.local" with "domain.local,mother.com".